# How to Parse multiple DESCENDANTS in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to parse multiple Descendants but do not know how to parse.

See my XML Document:

```
<root>

  <withoutGroup>
    <Id>123</tabId>
    <Name>XYZ</tabName>
    <Url>ABC.htm</tabUrl>
    <Icon/>
  </withoutGroup>

 <group>

  <groupId>789</groupId>
  <groupName>TEST</groupName>

  <row>
    <Id>345</Id>
    <Name>PQR</Name>
    <Url>QWE.htm</Url>
    <Icon/>
  </row>
</group>

</root>
```

1. I want to Parse these Nodes:

   Id

   Name

   Url

   Icon

How to deal with it?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

List<LIST> list = new List<LIST>();

list = (from query in doc.Descendants("group")
       select new LIST
       {
          Id = Convert.ToInt64(query.Element("Id").Value),
          Name = query.Element("Name").Value
        }).ToList();
```

**e.Result is my XML Document**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to select Id, Name, Url, and Icon from various parent element name (`row` and `withoutGroup` elements in this particular case). This is one possible way :

```
.......
//list all possible parent elements
var parentElements = new[] {"row", "withoutGroup"};
//get descendants having element name listed in parentElements variable
list = (from query in doc.Descendants()
                         .Where(o => parentElements.Contains(o.Name.LocalName))
        select new LIST
        {
          Id = (long)query.Element("Id"),
          Name = (string)query.Element("Name"),
          Url = (string)query.Element("Url"),
          Icon = (string)query.Element("Icon"),
        }).ToList();
```

BTW, you can cast `XElement` directly to one of types listed in [Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) section, as shown in above example.

Comment: har07, I shall try it. Thank you very much man. Looking like it will be perfectly work. Thanks!!

Comment: har07, thank you very much brother, its working like a charm. Keep it up. Thanks!!